# how to use word_limiter for get between 4th and 7th words

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hı;
ı want use word_limieter for my string 
for example

```
$string="this is a story of a man who was live in LA";
echo word_limiter($string, 4);
```

it's print on screen : this is a story

but ı want to get between 4th  and 7th  words (story of a man)

how can ı do it ?

Comment: Just another day in the life, huh? @Jay

Comment: Roger that! @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with `word_limiter()` but you can with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). Note the starting word is its position in the array:

```
$string="this is a story of a man who was live in LA";
$wordArr = explode(' ', $string);
$new = array_slice($wordArr, 3, 4); // starting word and length
$sentence = implode(' ', $new);
echo $sentence;
```

You can write a function with this in where you pass the string and array positions:

```
function new_word_limiter($string, $start, $end) {
    $wordArr = explode(' ', $string);
    $new = array_slice($wordArr, $start, $end);
    $sentence = implode(' ', $new);
    return $sentence;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
new_word_limiter($string, 3, 4); // either echo or assign to variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :) `substr(string,start,length)`

```
echo substr("this is a story of a man who was live in LA", 10,14);
```

for your purpose you can use
//substr($string,5,15)